# Cisco IOS: Is it possible to SSH into a Linux server with PubkeyAuthentication?

Tags: ssh, cisco, ssh-keys

I'm on a Cisco 2900 router running IOS ver 15.4. I have run `show ip ssh` and get the following:

```
SSH Enabled - version 2.0
Authentication methods:publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
Authentication timeout: 120 secs; Authentication retries: 3
Minimum expected Diffie Hellman key size : 1024 bits
IOS Keys in SECSH format(ssh-rsa, base64 encoded):
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAYQDexiovLMJlGyTplQW4EfbzBrcOve5HCsJ0fZ4RKxJQ
0w2oWA/BEMSABV5YEWkK6lhgt5ZqupeZxYGpIZMGwQa2qKJ6KLjWqp3tW99mUGigIhNhCA84giqj03kN
Zdpb650=
```

I have placed the `ssh-rsa` line into my authorized_keys file on my Linux server. I have tested that password-less authentication works starting from a different Linux server and logging into the target server.

In my sshd_config on the server, I have set `PasswordAuthentication no`, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`, and `PubkeyAuthentication yes`. I have examined the sshd log (with debug flags set) and don't see any clear error messages.

I get the following error when I try to log in with `ssh -l root 10.10.34.77`:

```
*Feb 18 22:20:50.608: %SSH-3-AUTH_METH_ERR: Server does not support
password or keyboard-interactive authentication
```

Because of the above error, I believe the issue is that the Cisco 2900 is not configured to attempt PubkeyAuthentication (only password and keyboard), and I can't so far figure a way to enable it. `ssh -o` on the 2900 only supports the `numberofpasswordprompts` options and I've looked through all available `ip ssh ?` choices when in config mode.

Can anyone confirm or deny these results? Thanks